# What on the arduino is generating the following signal?

Tags: arduino, signal, oscilloscope

I was playing around with looping a scope probe and placing that loop over various parts of different circuits. I tested a few different boards, but the arduino mega came out strongest, with quite a clear 32MHz signal being coupled into the loop. What is this signal, and where is it coming from?

Notes:

- The image of the loop over the arduino is where I could get the strongest signal.
- Pressing 'reset' on the arduino would stop the signal.
- The arduino was running the "ArduinoISP" sketch.
- The scope is acquiring on average mode with 256 averages.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Harmonics of the 16MHz clock.

Comment: I was also thinking along these lines, but this is the strongest signal I could find on the board - surely the original 16MHz signal would be stronger than the 32MHz harmonic? I'm open to be very wrong!

Comment: You could make a smaller loop to trace the location better, also doing the averaging can hide a lot of information.

Comment: The 16MHz probably is stronger, but your loop may be more senstive to the higher frequencies.  Also, you might try using finer resolution on the FFT.  You are using 50MHz per division,  but looking at multiples of a 16MHz signal.

Comment: also try actually measuring the time between adjacent peaks. It seems to me that you're relying on the FFT entirely.